# Map backslash in VIM

Tags: vim

I have Vim EasyMotion running by pressing:

```
Backslash Backslash <key>
```

I want to map this as `Ctrl+,` so I can do `Ctrl+, <key>`:

```
map <C-,> <Bslash><Bslash>
map <C-,> \\
```

But none of them worked. Has the backslash be escaped somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR: `<C-,>` won't work; choose another key combination.**

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.

Answer (score 2):

According to `:help map_backslash`, you are right to use `<Bslash>`.  The problem is that vim does not seem to recognize `<C-,>` in the `:map` command.  For example,

```
:map <C-,> :echo 'foo'<CR>
```

does not have the expectred effect.  Either dig into this further or choose a different key.

Comment: FWIW I was able to get the following binding to work: `noremap <C-Bslash> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>`.